# Fixed sidebar leaves responsive wrapper

Tags: html, css, responsive, sidebar, sticky

Why does my sidebar leave out of wrapper when its width reaches 1920px? I know I set the max-width on wrapper in order to maintain the size for 4k and bigger screens, but how do I keep the sidebar within the wrapper even when the size of the screen goes over 1920px?

```css
html {
  background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1920px;
  border: 2px dotted violet;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0;
}


/*first section*/

.section {
  margin-left: 150px;
  border: 2px dotted yellow;
}

.publicarea {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 10rem auto;
  border: 2px dotted blue;
}

.img-bookcontainer {
  min-width: 10rem;
  min-height: auto;
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px dotted red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-bookcontainer img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="/images/franzen-vertical-transparent.webp" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="publicarea">
      <div class="img-bookcontainer">
        <img src="/images/crossroads-3d-1.webp" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```